# Adding files in to SP Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-form

So, I have a file saved on my Desktop from a guy who created the file in SPD (he is no longer here and I'm an intern with no one to help me out). I need to add it in Designer where I have 36 subsites and many lists. The file only concern one list.

How do I open this file, and use it correctly?
And also, is there a rubbish bin in Designer? I need to find a missing form..

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What kind of file is it? Is it a list saved as a .stp file? There is access to the recycle bin from designer, as well from the subsites/sitecollections itself.

Comment: Yes, it's .stp. I found recycle bin but it was empty. I have tried to create new forms too instead of using the old files. But then my problem is how SP will use that form? I set it to default and defined URL in the html.

Comment: Do you have site collection administrator rights to begin with?

Comment: Yes, I have the same rights as the owner. I started editing one of the lists in Designer and it was easily done. Now I have a lot of problems editing Another list.

Comment: Owner may have full control over a site or subsite, but as a site collection administrator you gain access to a lot more which would make things easier for you. To begin with there is a second recycle bin where everything in a site collection that everyone else has deleted exists if you need to reach something that you did not delete (given that it is within a 30-50 days since they deleted something). Then you can upload your stp/list file to the web galleries and make it available to all the subsites in the site collection. What did you edit in the list? Columns or code behind?

Comment: Ok, I have not been here that long and no one here has a clue how this works.. I still can't find the missing form from designer. But when I try to open a form in the same subsite, the form is opened in different subsite and it's empty. This is strange. I edited code behind, there were two buttons: "save" and "exit" which I only changed where it should redirect to. And now I want to do the same thing in my other list. In the existing forms, edit, new and disp.aspx, I can't find the buttons.